# Спарсить из документа xml вложенные значения через консоль

Tags: linux

Спарсить из документа xml через консоль вложенные значения `CadastralNumber`.

Я пробовал несколько вариантов не работает:
1 вариант

```
grep -oPm1 "(?<=Flat CadastralNumber>)[^<]+" \
     "kv_30d5b1a1-1d80-4c79-a132-19cea9205343.xml"
```

2 вариант

```
echo "cat //*[local-name()='KPOKS']/*[local-name()='Realty']/*[local-name()='Flat']/*[local-name()='CadastralNumber']" | \
    xmllint --shell kv_30d5b1a1-1d80-4c79-a132-19cea9205343.xml | \
    sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
```

в первом варианте без вложенных  других значений атрибута вижу

контент файла:

```
<KPOKS xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/outgoing/kpoks/4.0.1" xmlns:smev="urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/supplementary/commons/1.0.1" xmlns:num="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/numbers/1.0" xmlns:adrs="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/address-output/4.0.1" xmlns:spa="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/entity-spatial/5.0.1" xmlns:param="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/parameters-oks/2.0.1" xmlns:cer="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/certification-doc/1.0" xmlns:doc="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/document-output/4.0.1" xmlns:flat="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/assignation-flat/1.0.1" xmlns:ch="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/cultural-heritage/2.0.1"> <Realty> <Flat CadastralNumber="78:34:0004286:9556" State="01" DateCreated="2012-09-19">
```

Comment: добавь пример входных данных... `xmllint`'ом можно это сделать надёжно и просто...

Comment: Чисто bash или другие языки можно использовать?

Comment: Php если только :)

Comment: Владимир я начала файла и пути указал в задаче под строчкой  контент файла:

Comment: `xmllint test.xml --xpath "//*[local-name()='Flat']/@CadastralNumber"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему как-то адекватно обработать namespace'ы xmllint'ом всё же нельзя, так что придётся использовать тот же монструозный синтаксис:

```
xmllint --xpath \
    "string(//*[local-name()='KPOKS']/*[local-name()='Realty']/*[local-name()='Flat']/@CadastralNumber)" \
    my.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

например, можно воспользоваться программой *xml2* [из одноимённого пакета](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=xml2&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all):

```
$ cat file.xml | xml2 | grep CadastralNumber
error: Extra content at the end of the document
/KPOKS/Realty/Flat/@CadastralNumber=78:34:0004286:9556
```

---

сообщение об ошибке вызвано некорректностью синтаксиса приведённого фрагмента (незакрытые теги).

Comment: Useless use of cat